# How and where can I calculate constant $k\approx1,895$?

Tags: calculus, constants, euler-mascheroni-constant

We know, that
$$e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}^{}\left[1+\frac{1}{1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\cdots\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right]$$
If $x_{m}=m(x_{m-1}-1)$ and $x_{0}=e$, then
$$x_{1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}^{}\left[1+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\cdots\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right]$$
$$x_{2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}^{}\left[1+\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\left(1+\cdots\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right]$$
$$x_{m}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}^{}\left[1+\frac{1}{m+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{m+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{m+3}\left(1+\cdots\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right]$$
$$\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n}\left(x_{m}-1\right)\approx\ln(n)+k$$
How and where can I calculate this constant? Is there relationship with this constant and $\gamma$?

If I made some mistakes, sorry for my English.

Comment: I have a problem with $x_{m}=m(x_{m-1}-1)$ and $x_0=e$ since this would give $x_m=e \Gamma (m+1)-e m \Gamma (m,1)$. More than likely, I am missing a point. Could you tell me where I am stupid ? By the way, how did you compute the number ?

Comment: Thank you for comment! Sorry, but I not understand your transform. I calculate constant in excel, but for $n=10^6$ it is few right terms. I want to calculate it more precisely.

Comment: It looks like $k = Ei(1) \approx 1.89511781635593675546652$ where $Ei(x)$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general $m \in \mathbb{N}$, it is easy to see
$$x_m = m!\left(e - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k!}\right)
\quad\implies\quad x_m - 1 
= m!\left(e - \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{1}{k!}\right)
= \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{m!}{k!}$$

This leads to
$$\begin{align}x_m - 1 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{m!}{(m+k+1)!}
&= \frac{1}{m+1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\frac{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(m+k+2)}\\
&= \frac{1}{m+1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1 (1-t)^m \frac{t^k}{k!} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{m+1} + \int_0^1 (1-t)^m (e^t-1)dt
\end{align}
$$
Summing $m$ from $0$ to $n$, we get

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^n (x_m - 1) 
&= H_{n+1} + \sum_{m=0}^n\int_0^1 (1-t)^m (e^t-1)dt\\
&= H_{n+1} + \int_0^1 \frac{1-(1-t)^{n+1}}{1-(1-t)} (e^t-1) dt\\
&= H_{n+1} + \int_0^1 (1 - (1-t)^{n+1}) \frac{e^t-1}{t}dt
\end{align}
$$
where $H_n = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m}$ is the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Notice for $t \in (0,1)$, MVT tell us for some $\xi \in (0,t)$,
$\frac{e^t - 1}{t} = e^{\xi t} \in (1, e^t) \subset (1,e)$. This allows us
to bound the $n$ dependent piece in above integral as

$$\frac{1}{n+2} \le \int_0^1 (1-t)^{n+1} \frac{e^t - 1}{t} dt \le \frac{e}{n+2}$$

We also know for large $n$, 
$$H_n = \log n + \gamma + O\left(\frac1n\right)$$
Combine these, we can conclude

$$\sum_{n=0}^n (x_m - 1) = \log n + k + O\left(\frac1n\right)
\quad\text{ where }\quad
k = \gamma + \int_0^1 \frac{e^t-1}{t} dt$$
Using an CAS, we find the integral above has a closed form in terms of 
[exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)
${\rm Ei}(x)$. The end result is

$$
k = \gamma + \left( {\rm Ei}(1) - \gamma\right) = {\rm Ei}(1)
\approx 1.89511781635593675546652...
$$